# Как правильно задать post запрос?

Tags: python, requests

Пробую создать тестовую компанию в mytarget, для чего нужно отправить запрос вида

```
POST /api/v1/campaigns.json HTTP/1.1
Host: target-sandbox.my.com
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 136
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, compress
Authorization: Bearer token

{"name": "Test campaign", "package": {"id": 18}, "targetings": {"regions": [188], "sex": "MF", "age": [20, 21], "pads": [{"id": 5206}]}}
```

С первой половиной у меня получилось, а как передать тот участок, что начинается с `{"name"` ?

Я пробовал сделать следующим образом, но получаю ошибку 400:

```
header = {
    'Host':'target-sandbox.my.com',
    'Content-Type':'application/json',
    'Content-Length':'136',
    'Accept-Encoding':'gzip,deflate,compress',
    'Authorization':'Bearer token'
}

company = {
    "name": "Test campaign",
    "package": {"id": 18},
    "targetings": {"regions": [188],"sex": "MF", "age": [20, 30],"pads": [{"id": 5206}]}
}

r = requests.post(
    'https://target-sandbox.my.com/api/v1/campaigns.json',
    data=json.dumps(company),
    headers = header
)
```

Не подскажите, в чем у меня ошибка?

Comment: Token рабочий подставляли?

Comment: Во-первых, подставьте токен, во-вторых, уберите Content-Length

Comment: Да, токен подставлял. Даже если убрать Content-Length, то возвращает ошибку

Comment: Да, на python .

Comment: попробуйте `json=company` вместо `data=json.dumps`. уберите все заголовки кроме Authorization